# (React) Reason Why can't resolve img css background img in css?

Tags: css, reactjs, image, snap.svg

I tried to post img by background url in css but error keeps occour like this...

```
Error: Can't resolve './src/resource/Original.svg' in 'C:\Users\User\IdeaProjects\demo\personal-blog\src\components\Sidebar'
```

Why is this error happening?

// this is component code

```
        <Link to={'/'}>
            <div className="logo"></div>
        </Link>
```

// Problematic css file

```
.Sidebar .logo {
background: url("src/resource/Logo/Resizable Vector Files/Original.svg");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use JSS styling inside your component file instead of CSS. so you should code your component like below:

```
import backgroundImg from './src/resource/Original.svg'
const styles = {
    main: {
        backgroundImage: `url(${backgroundImg})`
    }
}
.
.
.
<Link to={'/'}>
            <div style={styles.main}></div>
        </Link>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think in your *Sidebar.js* file `./src/resource/Original.svg` is not imported correctly

Answer (score 1):

either you typed `./src/resource/Original.svg` wrong or you didn't give `background-image:url();`